# Select Table (FROM) by string

Tags: php, mysql

**Is it possible, to use a dynamic value inside a SELECT FROM sql command?**

```
Database->prepare("SELECT bomb FROM ? WHERE id=?")
    ->execute($strTable,$strID);
```

result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception Exception with message Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with PHP...

Comment: Why? Does any sql command directly access mysql without layers in between?

Comment: by the way what library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$strTable` is from a safe source just use

```
Database->prepare("SELECT bomb FROM $strTable WHERE id=?")
    ->execute($strID);
```

Answer (score 6):

No. The table name cannot be a parameter of the query. You'd need to construct your query string first, concatenating the table name in.

Comment: that's poor. do you know a workaround concept maybe that you can share?

Comment: Any clue where this is documented?

Comment: @msec I gave you the workaround. Build your query into a string and concatenate the table name into that string.

Answer (score 2):

Your missing te bindParam statements. I don't think you can do the table name other than doing a php variable like @Alex did.  Here is code for a prepared statement:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT bomb FROM $tablename WHERE id=:strID");
$stmt->bindParam(':strID', $id);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

PHP Manaual refernce: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: How?  Using parameters it's near impossible for sql injection.  that is unless he's allowing the user to input his table name which in that case it should be hacked. "If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur."

Comment: what about $tablename = 'foobar WHERE 1=1 --', since we don't know where $tablename come from kind of dangerous

Comment: yes that is the one place it could be injected but if a developer is going to allow that variable to get data from an outside source that's his problem.  As a developer my tablename variable is only accessible from my codebase and I control what goes into it.

Answer (score 1):

usually those database abstraction layer relies on prepared statement to handle the place holder feature. The prepared statement feature of the RDBM compile the query, I don't think it's possible to prepare the query if the table is not specified.

You should use the escapement function of your library and include the table name in the query.

example:

```
$tablename = escapement_function($strTable);
Database->prepare("SELECT bomb FROM {$tablename} WHERE id=?")
        ->execute($strID);
```